# How to set cart for a day

Tags: php

I am working on a shopping cart application. when user select particular product, then that product's id, quantity and price store in session. But when I close the browser all data from $_SESSION['cart'] is deleted, but I want when again I visit my site the last selected entity should be display. I am using price, qty and product id as -

```
<?
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
$_SESSION['cart'][0]['productId'] = $pid;
$_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty'] = 1;
$_SESSION['cart'][0]['price'] = $price
?>
```

please tell me how to retain the selected values in session even after closing the browser. If you have any other approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, save the data to the cookies or database!
Session lasts until timeout (if there is any) or when you close the browser.

Comment: Is there any way by which i could set my cart timing for a day.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the session data just set a cookie along with it:

```
setcookie('cart' , true, time()+60*60*24*7);
setcookie('productID' , $pid, time()+60*60*24*7);
setcookie('qty' , '1', time()+60*60*24*7);
setcookie('price' , $price, time()+60*60*24*7);
```

Than within a global header check to see if a person is not signed in (via session variable existing) and if they are not, check to see if the cookie exists, and if it is, populate your cart via that.

You will of course need to initiate a new session, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `session.cookie_lifetime` in your `php.ini`. It is `0` by default. I think it is why your session expires when the browser is closed.

Set it to `86400` for setting session cookie lifetime to a day, and recheck your site. I think it will resolve your issue.

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

[php.net article](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: That is not true. Session is *always* destroyed when you close your browser.

Comment: Sessions are stored in server. Unless browser tells server when it is closed, I think, sessions will exist.

Comment: Correct, they are stored on server side, but there is no way to regain them after browser restart.

Comment: Yes Renku still it is not working after setting the session.cookie_lifetime in php.ini.